# link item to parsed hrefs in scrapy

Tags: python, parsing, scrapy

**Set-up**

Using scrapy I scrape housing ads.

Per [ad-overview page](https://kamernet.nl/huren/kamers-amsterdam), I obtain a list with hrefs linking to individual ads. By means of a for-loop, the hrefs are sent to a second parser function to obtain housing characteristics per ad.

```
def parse(self, response):
        # for href in list with hrefs
        for href in response.xpath(
                '//*[@id]/@href',
                ).extract()[1:-1]:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href),
                     callback=self.parse_ad)

def parse_ad(self, response):
# here follows code to obtain housing characteristics per ad

    yield {'char1': char1,
           'char2': char2,}
```

This works fine.

---

**Problem**

Besides the hrefs, I also obtain a list of postal codes from the ad-overview page using,

```
response.xpath('//*[@id]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/meta').extract()
```

Ultimately I would like to have,

```
    yield {'char1': char1,
           'char2': char2,
           'postal code': postal_code}
```

but I am unsure how to,

1. Make python select both the `href` and its corresponding `postal_code`
2. Carry the `postal_code` over to the `yield` function under `parse_ad()`

How do I go about?

Comment: 1. Do you want to use `href`, extracted in a fucntion `parse`?
2. You may have several `yield` calls in one function to "return" several dicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "carry on" things from a callback method to an another callback method, use [`meta`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta):

```
def parse(self, response):
    for search_result in response.css(".room-tile.rowSearchResultRoom"):
        postal_code = search_result.css("meta[itemprop=postalCode]::attr(content)").extract_first()
        href = search_result.xpath("@href").extract_first()

        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href),
                             meta={'postal_code': postal_code},
                             callback=self.parse_ad)

def parse_ad(self, response):
    postal_code = response.meta['postal_code']

    # get char1 and char2..

    yield {'char1': char1,
           'char2': char2,
           'postal_code': postal_code}
```